# Adding a picker view on onclick of a text box

Tags: html, objective-c, ipad, uipickerviewcontroller

How can I add a picker view on onclick of a text box.

Here's the code I am using for the text box:

```
<td>
<input value="0" id="LVAD1" name="h9" style="height: 22px;width:48px;
                        margin-left:2px;"readonly="readonly"; type="text">
</td>
```

I created separate `PickerView.h` and `pickerView.m` files and have created the delegates.

I just need the know how to provide connection between the pickerview and textbox.

Comment: Could you tell what do you mean by picker view ? is it a date picker ? or else ? I think you must use onclick event for textbox and display:none property for picker view!

Comment: Hi niko, i am not looking for a date picker.i am looking for a Picker view - Displays a spinning wheel or slot-machine motif of values.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this is what you are looking for: at the start, set `style="display:none"` for the picker and use `onclick` event for textbox.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function enable_picker()
   {
   var picker = document.getElementById('picker');
   picker.style.display="block";
   }
</script>
</head>
   <h1 id="picker" style="display:none">hello</h1>
   <input type="text" onclick="enable_picker()"/>
```

Don't forget to set `id="picker"` for picker view
or, to be simple, just go for jQuery plugins hide, show properties and animation effects!

I don't really know what a picker is but the above code pops out `hello` when you click the textbox.

Comment: Thanks for the help niko, this gave me a idea how to do it.